# plotting two plots near each other in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I plot these two plots, but in latex it plot them under each other, I do not want they be ploted under each other, I want they be ploted near each other by some distances? how can I do that?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=54mm,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=center,
xmin = -3,    xmax = 3,
ymax =  2.2,
xtick={-2, -1, 0, 1, 2},
ytick={1},
xlabel={$t$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
ylabel={$h(t)$}
            ]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none] coordinates
    {(0,0) (0,1) (2,1) (2,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=54mm,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=center,
xmin = -3,    xmax = 3,
ymax =  2.2,
xtick={-2, -1, 0, 1, 2},
ytick={1},
xlabel={$t$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
ylabel={$h(t)$}
            ]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none] coordinates
    {(0,0) (0,1) (2,1) (2,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Then you should remove the empty lines between the plots.

Answer (score 1):

Add `\qquad` between the two plots:

```
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want you can also follow [this strategie](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690972/245790):

- create individual files for each `Tikz` drawing and compile them
- use `\includegraphics` to include their `.pdf` s
- which you can embed in a `figure environment`
- which can use `subfigures` to place them next to each other, with sub-captions

Next is a sreenshot from said link, which also tells you about the advantages for your workflow. And it schows you two Tikz drawing side by side ...

---

[image: code]